# Firebase Code not working on encrypted APK

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using google purchase library 4.0.0, all my firebase codes work but after a code blog is encrypted it doesn't work. When I encrypt the apk and test it on my device, it doesn't do what it's supposed to do in firebase. There is no logchat as I don't know how to output log in encrypted apk.

How do I solve this problem?

Note: I am calling LoggEds method inside onCreate.
When membershipcontrol is called, some data in firebase needs to be updated but is not. This debug works fine in apk

My Code:

```
 public static void LoggEds(){
    trackItems = new ArrayList<Track>();
    adapter = new TracksAdapter(MyApplication.getInstance(), trackItems);
    trackItems.clear();
    mDatabaseReference.child("/track-kontrol/").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot snap: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    abc ne = snap.getValue(abc.class);
                    kontrolLst.add(ne.kontrol);
                }

            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    final ValueEventListener trackListener = new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Track track = dataSnapshot.getValue(Track.class);
            if(track != null) {
                track.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                for (int i = 0; i < trackItems.size(); i++) {
                    Track track1 = trackItems.get(i);
                    if (track1.getId().equals(track.getId())) {
                        trackItems.remove(i);
                    }
                }
                trackItems.add(0, track);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    ValueEventListener user_tracksListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Iterable<DataSnapshot> user_trackChildren = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot track : user_trackChildren) {
                String key = track.getKey();
                mDatabaseReference.child("/tracks/" + key).addValueEventListener(trackListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };

    mDatabaseReference.child("/user-tracks/" + getUid()).addValueEventListener(user_tracksListener);

}

private void setNextKontrol(){
    kontrolLst = removeDuplicates(kontrolLst);
    Collections.sort(kontrolLst);

    kontrol = 1;

    for(int index=0;index<kontrolLst.size();index++){
        if(kontrolLst.get(index)!=index+1){
            kontrol=index+1;

            return;
        }
    }
    kontrol=kontrolLst.size()+1;
}

public <T> ArrayList<T> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<T> list)
{
    ArrayList<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (T element : list) {

        if (!newList.contains(element)) {

            newList.add(element);
        }
    }

    return newList;
}

public void membershipkontrol() {
    User getUsers = MyApplication.getInstance().getUser();
    setNextKontrol();
    if (trackItems.size() < 1) return;
    for (Track item : trackItems) {
        if (MyApplication.getInstance().getUser() != null) {
            MyApplication.getInstance().setUser(getUsers);
            User getUsersControl = MyApplication.getInstance().getUser();

            String trackId = item.getId();
            Map<String, Object> hasMap = new HashMap<>();
            hasMap.put("membership", getUsersControl.membership);
            hasMap.put("kontrol", kontrol);
            Map<String, Object> hasMaptWo = new HashMap<>();
            hasMaptWo.put("kontrol", kontrol);
            Map<String, Object> hasMaptHr = new HashMap<>();
            hasMaptHr.put("expiredtime", getUsersControl.expiredTime);
            mDatabaseReference.child("/tracks").child(trackId).updateChildren(hasMap);
            mDatabaseReference.child("/tracks").child(trackId).updateChildren(hasMaptHr);
            mDatabaseReference.child("/track-kontrol").child(trackId).updateChildren(hasMaptWo);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check the Proguard rules when making the release APK? Maybe some of the code is obfuscated when optimizing the app.

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?